# Unable to generate classes using maven from XSD

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, xsd-validation

Error whiel trying to generate class files from xsd using maven

I have the below xsd file:-

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0">
 <xs:element name="ADI">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Metadata">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="AMS">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Asset_Class"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Asset_ID"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Asset_Name"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Product"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Provider"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Provider_ID"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Version_Major"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Version_Minor"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="App_Data" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="App" use="optional"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Name" use="optional"/>
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Value" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

While trying to generate classes it is throwing the below expection

> lineNumber: 56; columnNumber: 33; Property "Value" is already defined.
>   Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

Tried using the below binding file in the same location of the xsd, but still does not work

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="BaseADI.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='App_Data']">        
            <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='Value']">
                <jxb:property name='ValueAttribute' />
            </jxb:bindings>         
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Then i get a parse expection:-

> ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [
>   .........../binding.xjb{6,55}]. com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2

Is the binding file the right option to slove the issue.
Any comments or suggestions is appreciated.